# How come I get so many InflateException crashes recently from Samsung devices running Android 10?

Tags: android, android-inflate, android-10.0, inflate-exception

### Background

For some reason on [one of my apps](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lb.contacts_sync), I get relatively a lot of crashes recently of "android.view.InflateException" . I think it has started over the last version or two.

### The problem

According to both the Play Console and Crashlytics, for some reason the crashes occur only on Samsung devices that have Android 10.

It might be a coincidence for now, as Samsung devices are quite popular, but still it is suspicious to me.

On Play Console, it doesn't say much:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZ8D4.png]

On Crashlytics, it seems it's related to inflation of views, but it doesn't make sense, because it says it's "Error inflating class TextView" or "Error inflating class androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar" :

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/brMgU.png]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PGRCe.png]

### What I've tried

Searching the Internet and here, sadly I couldn't find a similar case.

What I can think about is that maybe it's some bug on Google's SDKs that I use, which have some issues with Samsung devices, as they got Android 10 only recently. And since it occurred only over the past 1-2 versions that might be it.

I actually use latest versions of Google's SDKs. However, I don't even use the fancy stuff there. On the Toolbar one, my layout has "CoordinatorLayout", "AppBarLayout", "Toolbar" and "FragmentContainerView" (for the preferences), for example. Here's its layout:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activities.activity_settings.SettingsActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true" android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            app:title="@string/settings" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Here are some of the dependencies I tried to update to, in order to reduce how common the bug is :

- 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha03'
- 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta4'
- 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.2.0-rc01'
- 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.2.0-rc04'
- 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
- 'dev.chrisbanes:insetter:0.2.0'
- 'dev.chrisbanes:insetter-ktx:0.2.0'

### The questions

How come it happens ? What could have caused it? I don't see it mentioned anywhere.

Is this perhaps a known bug? How come it's only for Samsung devices with Android 10? I tested it already on my own Pixel 4 with Android 10 (and other devices with other versions of Android) , and it worked fine...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems it was all because I used a system color that isn't defined on some devices:

**res/values-v29/colors.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="colorAccent">@*android:color/accent_device_default_light</color>
</resources>
```